# Electron Auto-typer typing slow when not in app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm making an Electron auto-typer, and I'm using the module `@nut-tree/nut-js` to do my auto-typing.

I watched [Fireship's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yqDxhR2XxE) on setting up the electron app. Then, I created a file called `typer.js` and referenced it in HTML.

To test the auto-typer, I created a button in the HTML file to initialize the script (button has an ID of `lol`, don't ask). I then tested my auto-typer in (1) a text box in the HTML file and (2) a document in my browser.

The code works fine in the app. However, when I test it in my browser, it types the words really slowly. It should type a letter every 15 milliseconds, but in the browser it's more like a letter every second.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>

    <button type='button' id='lol'>submit</button> 

    <form>
        <input type='text'></input>
    </form>

    <script defer src='typer.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js` (the file that initializes the Electron app, correct me if I said this wrong)

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

`typer.js`:

```js
//just an async function to wait some milliseconds before executing another line
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

//the button that i was talking about
const lol = document.getElementById('lol');

//what i type
input = 
`how to solve this problem`;

lol.onclick = async() => {

    const { keyboard } = require('@nut-tree/nut-js');
    keyboard.config.autoDelayMs = 15;

    await delay(3000)

    await keyboard.type(input);
}
```

Here's a [video replay](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FwEwEP-vHC7TH8j3xbSZSAePMKaGuHqs/view?usp=sharing). (Oh, and uh, just realized I revealed my real name, but whatever)